# Problem at the end of a stanza - verse Package

Tags: verse

I'm learning LaTeX, and have a problem with the `\\!` macro.

When I write for example :

```
    Comme un soleil couchant dans un ciel nébuleux. \\!
```

This is what I get on my pdf:

```
    Comme un soleil couchant dans un ciel nébuleux.
    !
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As I read on http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/verse/verse.pdf, "If the lines in a poem are to be numbered then \\! must be used at the end of the last line in each stanza (the \\ macro increments the line numbers)."

Comment: And yes, I use french babel, and use the macro within a verse environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a suggestion, but I am not sure this will work in any case:

Use `\shorthandoff{!}` to disable the special meaning of `!` for french typography (whatever this meaning might be)

It can be enabled later on again with `\shorthandon{!}`, if necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{!}
\poemlines{1}
\begin{verse}
Comme un soleil couchant dans un ciel nébuleux. \\
Comme un soleil couchant dans un ciel nébuleux. \\!
Comme un soleil couchant dans un ciel nébuleux. \\
Comme un soleil couchant dans un ciel nébuleux. \\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SamuelDiebolt: Ok, happy TeXing then ;-)